# Aurelia bundling gives 404 errors

Tags: aurelia

I have the standard configs of the Aurelia Skeleton Navigation App installed and when I try to bundle the app for deployment, I get a whole list of 404 errors of modules that I am missing. The problem is that I am not using these modules, and it still requires them. Here's a list of what it looks like.

[image]

Any suggestions how I can fix this?

Comment: When you bundle, how are you serving the app?

Comment: @AshleyGrant Via a webserver which is serving the files from the export folder

Comment: Sometimes a cache can cause issues. Make sure your config.js is up to date, then open your chrome devtools, right click on the refresh button by the URL bar and Empty Cache and Hard Reload. Let me know if that helps or not.